# Implement Streamlined Identity Flows with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-authentication, actions-on-google

I'm trying to implement Google's [Streamlined Identity Flows](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) for authenticating users on Actioins on Google with Spring Boot and Spring Security (OAuth).

I already managed to implement Google-SignIn but the server side is missing. I could implement every endpoint myself but as with most security concerns I think that it's better to use tested and proved frameworks or components. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use Spring Security's OAuth authorization server functionality.

1. How to implement the authorization endpoint that lets users authenticate with their browser and respond an authentication token
2. How to implement the JWT token endpoint

Is it possible to leverage the possibilities of Spring OAuth for this or do I have to create a custom endpoint with @Controller / @RestController for example.

Are their any tutorials or documentations on how to implement such a service with Spring Security?